# How to create a box plot from a frequency table

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, boxplot, frequency-table

In the table below, I have values and frequencies. I'd like to draw a box-plot using Jupyter Notebook. I googled it but not able to find any answers.

My idea is to create a column, 2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,...
But I think there must be a better way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

value=np.array([2,4,6,7,10])
freq=np.array([4,7,8,5,2])

# do something here

plt.boxplot(newdata)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use numpy's [repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
newdata = np.repeat(value,freq)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about repeat. This is cool. Thanks. Does Pandas have similar method?

Comment: Sure, [Series.repeat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html). In your case, newdata = df['value'].repeat(df['freq'])